# SQL Query to show a specific date only once

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site where I have to create a table using values from MySQL, something like 'https://alerts.flexoffers.com/v2/PublisherLog'.

What I have achieved right now shows all the entries on the base of warning or error. This means there will be multiple entries each day telling if it is an error or a warning.

What I need is that there is only one entry for a specific date in the date column. And then in respective warning and error columns, all the entries from that day add up and show the number of errors/warnings there were.

```
SELECT bctw_error_logs.`id`,
       SUM(if(bctw_error_logs.`severity_level` = '1', 1, 0)) as Warnings,
       SUM(if(bctw_error_logs.`severity_level` = '2', 1, 0)) as Errors,
       DAYNAME(`log_date`) as Day,
       DATE_FORMAT(`log_date`, "%M %d %Y") as Date
FROM bctw_error_logs group by bctw_error_logs.`id`;
```

This what I am using right now.

Comment: so it looks like you just need to not select id, and change the group by to group by log_date?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`. *What I need is that there is only one entry for a specific date in the date column.* What entry from all ones precisely? the earliest? latest? earliest, error if exists and warning if not? something else?